# How to override the default sorting of Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a **map-reduce** job in which the keys are numbers from 1-200. My intended output was **(number,value)** in the number order.
But I'm getting the output as :

```
1    value
10   value
11   value
   :
   : 
2    value
20   value
   :
   :
3    value
```

I know this is due to the default behavior of Map-Reduce to sort keys in ascending order.

I want my keys to be sorted in numerical order only. How can I achieve this?

Comment: how do you run mapreduce?

Comment: Hi, your question came to me in the editing queue.  I have edited it slightly, removing the sign off at the end, for instance.  However, the ***main*** problem with the question is that it doesn't show your code for how you use mapreduce.  You need to add this, so that people can help with why the keys are sorted in lexographical order rather than numerical and help you to fix this.  If you add this info, you'll be likely to get better help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `WritableComparator` in MapReduce framework would normally handle your numerical ordering if the key was `IntWritable`. I suspect it's getting a `Text` key thus resulting in lexicographical ordering in your case. Please have a look at the sample code which uses `IntWritable` key to emit the values:

**1) Mapper Implementaion**

```
package com.stackoverflow.answers.mapreduce;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class SourceFileMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text> {

    private static final String DEFAULT_DELIMITER = "\t";

    private IntWritable keyToEmit = new IntWritable();
    private Text valueToEmit = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        keyToEmit.set(Integer.parseInt(line.split(DEFAULT_DELIMITER)[0]));
        valueToEmit.set(line.split(DEFAULT_DELIMITER)[1]);
        context.write(keyToEmit, valueToEmit);
    }

}
```

**2) Reducer Implementation**

```
package com.stackoverflow.answers.mapreduce;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class SourceFileReducer extends Reducer<IntWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text> {

    public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        for (Text value : values) {
            context.write(key, value);
        }
    }

}
```

**3) Driver Implementation**

```
package com.stackoverflow.answers.mapreduce;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

public class SourceFileDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {

        Path inputPath = new Path(args[0]);
        Path outputDir = new Path(args[1]);

        // Create configuration
        Configuration conf = new Configuration(true);

        // Create job
        Job job = new Job(conf, "SourceFileDriver");
        job.setJarByClass(SourceFileDriver.class);

        // Setup MapReduce
        job.setMapperClass(SourceFileMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(SourceFileReducer.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(1);

        // Specify key / value
        job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        // Input
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, inputPath);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);

        // Output
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputDir);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        // Delete output if exists
        FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        if (hdfs.exists(outputDir))
            hdfs.delete(outputDir, true);

        // Execute job
        int code = job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
        System.exit(code);

    }

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I have to output one key as Text .That's why i used Text instead of IntWritable. In my job,one key should be Text.Considering this requirement, how can i find a solution ? –

Answer (score 3):

If I had to take a guess, I'd say that you are storing your numbers as Text objects and not IntWritable objects.

Either way, once you have more than one reducer, only the items within a reducer will be sorted, but it won't be totally sorted.

Comment: I have to output one key as Text .That's why i used Text instead of IntWritable. In my job,one key should be Text.Considering this requirement, how can i find a solution ?