# Mapreduce: Lexicographical ordering. Text and Int types

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I have a map reduce job that sorts through data found here:
http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Bank+Marketing

I currently have a job that sorts through the file and outputs a key value pair of the following format:
education type, bank balance, job, marital status, loan approval.

This works close to perfect. I get a list that has been edited as such with a number next to them if there is more than one person who is the same.

What I want to do is edit how the list is ordered without running more than one job or changing the output order.

An example of the output is:

```
unknown, 970, unemployed, married, yes  1
unknown, 9716, housemaid, married, no   1
unknown, 973, services, divorced, no    1
unknown, 973, services, divorced, yes   2
unknown, 974, services, single, no  1
unknown, 975, entrepreneur, married, no 1
unknown, 975, technician, divorced, no  1
unknown, 976, bluecollar, married, no   1
unknown, 98, admin, married, no 1
```

While the output does sort by education type (in this case unknown), I want to change the order within the output so that they are in descending balance order and not sorted by lexicographical order.
EG:

```
unknown, 98, admin, married, no 1
unknown, 970, unemployed, married, yes  1
unknown, 973, services, divorced, no    1
unknown, 973, services, divorced, yes   2
unknown, 974, services, single, no  1
unknown, 975, entrepreneur, married, no 1
unknown, 975, technician, divorced, no  1
unknown, 976, bluecollar, married, no   1
unknown, 9716, housemaid, married, no   1
```

The following question says I need to change the key type to something like intwritable but I can't do this as I am already sorting by a text value first. 
[How to override the default sorting of Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28898810/how-to-override-the-default-sorting-of-hadoop)

TLDR: Do I have to run multiple jobs to sort by two separate variable types within a key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the correct method to do this. For all those looking, A secondary sort is what is needed.

I used the documents here:

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/data-algorithms/9781491906170/ch01.html

To understand the implementation.